# How to run flyway:migrate on a cloned database

Tags: clone, flyway, migrate

We have a production database and we maintain it by using flyway.  Recently we cloned our production database to create a UAT database.  The UAT database has the same schema and data as that in production.  Now we try to run "mvn flyway:migrate" on the UAT database to test new flyway script.  However, we got

```
+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------+
| Version | Description           | Installed on        | State   |
+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 0.0.1   | script.1              |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.0.2   | script.2              |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.0.3   | script.3              |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.1.1   | script.4              |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.1.2   | script.5              |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.2.0   | script.6              |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.5.1   | script.7              |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.5.2   | script.8              |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.6.0   | script.9              |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.7.0   | script.10             |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.8.0   | script.11             |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.9.0   | script.12             |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.10.0  | script.13             |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.11.1  | script.14             |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.12.0  | script.15             |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.13.0  | script.16             |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.14.0  | script.17             |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.15.0  | script.18             |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.16.0  | script.19             |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.16.1  | script.20             |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.17.0  | script.21             |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.17.1  | script.22             |                     | <Baseln |
| 0.18.0  | script.23             |                     | <Baseln |
| 1       | << Flyway Baseline >> | 2016-11-07 08:11:33 | Baselin |
| 1.16.0  | script.19             | 2017-02-15 10:03:18 | Future  |
| 1.16.1  | script.20             | 2017-02-15 10:03:18 | Future  |
+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

The script.23 is a new script.  We expect the state is pending.
However, the state of all scripts became Baseln.  I searched the relating topics for a day but could not find scenarios closed to my case.  Is there any configuration on flyway (maven) I can use to run migrate command on a cloned database?  Please help.  (My database is SQL Server 2014, flyway version 4.0 ,maven version is 3.5, JDK version 1.7)

Thanks a lot.
Chi-Fu

Answer (score 0):

I think that all versions [lower than the baseline are not executed](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/baseline) - they are supposed to belong to the baseline.

If script.23 is a new migration it should have a version greater than the last version, typically 1.18.0 (According to standard flyway config, V1_18_0__script.23.sql rather than V0_18_0__script.23.sql).

After having renamed this file, do a repair before trying to migrate again.